# C# Chaining Actions

Tags: c#, action, chain

I want to achieve something similar to how tasks can be chained:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { })
    .ContinueWith((t) => { })
    .ContinueWith((t) => { })
    ...
    .ContinueWith((t) => { });
```

However, I don't need these actions to be run asynchronously. I want to be able to chain actions (Execute the first, then the second, then the third, etc), and most importantly, I want to add a

```
.Catch((a) => { }
```

Action that will be an action to execute when an error has been thrown by any of the actions in the chain.

At the end, I want it to look like this:

```
Actions.Factory.Execute(() => {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    if (foo != bar) 
        throw new Exception('Incompatible Types!);
}).Catch((ex) => {
    MyFancyLogger.LogError("Something strange happened: " + ex.Error.ToString();
});
```

I have tried implementing a Factory class that works on a derived class that inherits from the Action class, but unfortunately the 'Action' class is sealed, so that wont work.

**EDIT:**

My main reason for this is I want to record statistics on each wrapped action, as well as handle the error differently based on the severity. Currently I am doing this by executing one action with the following signature:

```
public static void ExecuteAction(this Action action, 
    string name = "", 
    int severity = 0, 
    bool benchmark = false, 
    bool logToDb = false, 
    [CallerMemberName]string source = "", 
    [CallerFilePath]string callerLocation = "", 
    [CallerLineNumber]int lineNo = 0) {
    // Wrap the whole method in a try catch
    try {
        // Record some statistics
        action.Invoke();
        // Record some statistics
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (severity > 3) {
             // Log to DB
        } else Logger.WriteError(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and calling it like so:

```
(() => {
    //this is the body
}).ExecuteAction("Description of the method", 3, true, false);
```

In my opinion that works well and it reads easily. Now I just want to add a .Catch to that:

```
(() => {
    //this is the body
})
.ExecuteAction("Description of the method", 3, true, false)
.Catch((e) => {
    MessageBox.Show("This shouldn't have happened...");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think method which execute all tasks one by one and wrapped by `try ... catch` will be enough, In case I understand you requirements correctly.

```
public async Task Execute(IEnumerable<Func<Task>> actions, Action catchAction)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            await action();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        catchAction(ex)
    }
}
```

Consumer of method above will be responsible for creating collection of tasks in correct order.´

However next requirement seems little bid confusing

> However, I don't need these actions to be run synchronously. I want to
> be able to chain actions (Execute the first, then the second, then the
> third, etc)

If don't need actions to be run synchronously, then you can start executing them all at once (approximately "at once") and observe their completion wrapped by `try .. catch`

```
public async Task Execute(IEnumerable<Func<Task>> actions, Action catchAction)
{
    var tasks = actions.Select(action => action());
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        catchAction()
    }
}
```

In response on the comment about readability

Of course, putting all actions inline will violate readability of any api which takes collection as parameter.

Usually you have methods of some instance or static methods, in this case call will look like

```
var actions = new Action[]
{
    StaticClass.Action1,
    SomeInstance.Action2,
    AnotherStaticClass.Action3
}

await Execute(actions, Logger.Log);
```

Another approach you can use is "Builder pattern"

```
public class Executor
{
    private List<Func<Task>> _actions;
    private Action<Exception> _catchAction;
    public Executor()
    {
        _actions = new List<Func<Task>>();
        _catchAction = exception => { };
    }

    public Executor With(Func<Task> action)
    {
        _actions.Add(action);
        return this;
    }

    public Executor CatchBy(Action<Exception> catchAction)
    {
        _catchAction = catchAction;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        var tasks = _actions.Select(action => action());
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _catchAction(ex)
        }            
    }
}
```

Then use it

```
Func<Task> doSomeDynamicStaff = () => 
{
    // Do something
}
var executor = new Executor()
    .With(StaticClass.DoAction1)
    .With(StaticClass.DoAction2)
    .With(StaticClass.DoAction3)
    .With(doSomeDynamicStaff)
    .CatchBy(Logger.Log);

await executor.Run();
```

Comment: How will you call this though, it should still be easy enough to read and figure out whats going on.. I have changed your Signature to the following to try and improve that: 

`public void Execute(Action catchAction, params Action[] actions) {  
...
}`
but  even that feels unreadable:

`Execute(() => {
                    // This is the Catch
                },
                    () => {
                        // This is the first action in the chain
                    }, () => {
                        // This is the second action in the chain
                    });`

Comment: @JohanAspeling, check updated answer. I little bid wonder, why you want call all actions "inline"? Instead you can introduce functions as variable, which will be much more readable, or even better group them in the class or static class

Comment: I have used this approach to fix my solution. Thanks for the help, it's 100% what I needed!